# How can I see and delete Email Messages Records in the org?

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, data, data-storage, admin

I was looking at our Data usage in the org and realized that 7% of our data storage is taken up by Email Message Records. [This document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_EmailMessage.htm) says EmailMessage represents Email Messages in the org. How can I see these emails and how can I delete them? Obviously, I can delete them using Apex as explained [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) but I want to know what they are before deleting them.

UPDATE: Looks like I do not have sufficent access to delete most of the email message records althought I have "Modify All Data" access.

Comment: What is stopping you from querying the fields you are interested in for each EmailMessage in your org?

Comment: I'm hoping that there is a UI for it. I don't want to write scripts and find out how to lay out the data properly to understand it. I also have thousands,which makes it impractical to do that and be confident about the results.

Comment: You could perform a data export using the standard Data Loader. This will create a .csv for you that you can work with a little easier. (https://dataloader.io/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=%27%2Bapex%20%2Bdata%20%2Bloader&utm_campaign=G_DataLoader_Search_Salesforce_Apex)